# Start script on boot up?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, x11, startup

I want to run a script when the system starts. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t "MyPC" -e "sh -c 'nohup firefox & nohup gedit & bash'" --tab -t "MYPC2" -e "sh -c 'ls -al;ls; bash'" > /home/user/gnome
```

So I copied my script to `/etc/init.d` and ran `update-rc.d boot-up defaults`

`boot-up` is name of my script.

Now, when I restart, the gnome-terminal is not opening (as wriiten in script), though I can see `/home/user/gnome` file being created which is empty.

I tried other methods like putting it in `/etc/rc.local` to no avail.

The only way the script runs is when I add it through `startup-Applications`.

Any idea How to make it work??

I am using Ububutu 12.10

Comment: `systemd` will help you :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok...Systemd is a service manager for  linux. It is simple and easy to use. You need to have an unit file that executes your script at the startup. You can specify the dependencies if you have any to run your startup program.If you can use `systemd` in your environment then I can give you information about the sample service to run from systemd.

Comment: According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd ubuntu's systemd is still very experimental, and works best on 15.04, but it might work ok on 14.10, so I doubt it's going to be much good on 12.04

Comment: `systemd` is the simplest suite to manage the services. I'm using systemd for almost one year and I didn't faced any problem even for my complex requirements.

Comment: If you can't use systemd, you probably have [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) on your Ubuntu 12.04 system.

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha : Because you are adding your script inside `/etc/init.d` you need to create a symlink for that. `ln -s /etc/init.d/your_script /etc/rc.d/`. It should work.Inform me if it works I'll update my answer.

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/561604/10127

Answer (score 4):

This script will not run correctly at boot time as `gnome-terminal`, `firefox` and `gedit` will expect a X session to be running.

The `init.d` and/or `systemd` route is too early in the boot process for your requirements.  You'd be better off creating a `.desktop` file and configuring your system to auto-start this on login.

Create a the file as follows:-

```
$ gedit ~/.config/autostart/my_stuff.desktop
```

and add the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Script
Exec=~/my_script.sh
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Note that `~/my_script.sh` should point to the script you've created. Save it.

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod o+x ~/.config/autostart/my_stuff.desktop
```

When you next log in, it should open your terminal, firefox and gedit for you.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your answer. Upvoted :). But how can you say this won't work from `systemd`. I'll run my unit file once the `x` is initialized.I mean i'll add `x` as my dependency to my unit file to delay it.

Comment: I _was_ going to mention that it's pointless starting those programs before X is running, but I got distracted by the systemd v upstart stuff. :)

Comment: @Thushi - X will be initialised as soon as you see the login screen.  However, if you're not logged in you won't have an X session for your applications to use and they'll bork. So even waiting for X is still too early to launch your script.

Comment: The environment I was working is not having the login screen.So I was in that context. Thank you for correcting me. :)

Comment: @Thushi - Even if you set up your user to automatically login, X will be up before the user is logged in and you may still end up in the situation where your script runs too early. I don't believe there is a `systemd` facility to run on login (but I may be wrong!).

Comment: @garethTheRed - Yeah X will be up before the user is logged in but `X` may not be the dependency for your unit file.We can identify the suitable service that runs after the login and we can add that dependency.But anyway OP is using 12.04 no need of `systemd`. I just introduced the alternate way to run the script at the startup :) .

Comment: @garethTheRed: I did as you said: I added following in .desktop: `[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=boot-up
Exec=~/test-scripts/boot-up
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` . My permissions for the above file:`-rwxrw-r-x  1 userA userA  105 Dec 15 18:08 my_stuff.desktop*`. STILL, it's not working and a empty `gnome` file is being created which shows that it is executed but no terminal, firefox is opened.

Comment: YES, it works !!

Comment: @garethTheRed: I am running `12.10` not `12.04` if that will make a difference? By mistake I had written `12.04` in the question

Comment: When I run /home/userA/test-scripts/boot-up on command line now, it gives `line 2: /home/userA/gnome: Permission denied` as `gnome` which was "created" has root permissions: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 15 18:38 gnome`

Comment: @garethTheRed: It worked after removing `init.d` script. Thanks. From the above discussion I understand that only after login the utilities like firefox gedit can be invoked not at boot time. Am I right?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha - Correct. All such applications will need access to the user's X session, which isn't available until logged in.